# Generating an Existential type with QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, existential-type

I'm struggling with this one - how could QuickCheck generate a value *for all* types? Maybe it could forge it, and only test types with the context `Arbitrary a => a`?

I'm just wondering how someone could make an instance of arbitrary for data constructors with an existential type:

```
data Foo a = Foo a (forall b. (a -> b, b -> a))
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a value of that type? Also, isn't that a rank-2 type, not an existential type?

Comment: Indeed, the only values of that type look at least as bad as `Foo a1 (const undefined, const a2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell what you're really trying to do, especially since your example type doesn't make a lot of sense. Consider something else:

```
newtype WrappedLens s t a b = WrappedLens (forall f . Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t)

newtype WL = WL (WrappedLens (Int, Int) (Int, Int) Int Int)
```

Is it possible to make an arbitrary `WL`? Sure! Just pass `fmap` explicitly and use the arbitrary function instance. Is it possible to make an arbitrary `WL` that's a law-abiding lens? Now that is a much taller order.

I would speculate that the hard thing about making arbitrary values involving higher rank types is not the types so much as the fact that they tend to involve functions in some fashion, and it's hard to constrain arbitrary functions to the ones you actually want to consider.